# pandas: retrieve values post group by sum

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas data frame(**"df"**) looks like :

```
                 name      id            time
1095             One       1     12:03:37.230812
1096             Two       2     10:56:29.314745
1097           Three       3     10:58:18.897624
1098           Three       3     09:45:38.755116
1099             Two       2     09:02:59.472508
1100             One       1     12:28:38.341024
```

On this, i did an operation which is

```
df = df.groupby(by=['id'])[['time']].transform(sum).sort('time', ascending=False)
```

On the resulting **df** I want to iterate and get response as name and total time. How can I achive that from last df(from groupby/transform response) ? So result should look something like this:

```
name      time

One       24:03:37.230812
Two       19:56:29.314745
Three     19:58:18.897624
```

Comment: time addition will not work via `sum`. Even if you add time via python's `datetime` and if the time addition goes over 24 hours then it will be printed as `00:03:37.230812` instead of `24:03:37.230812`

Comment: I have manage to put down a sample code. See if you get some idea from it https://gist.github.com/ajinkyapisal/118f8541cffcc2480ffe58f9dcd156b1

Comment: time addition was working fine.. response was bit different, it converts it into format n days hh:mm:ss. my challenge was to get the name as that was not part of later operations

Answer (score 1):

I think you need convert column `time` [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) first.

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `name` or `id` and aggregate `sum`:

```
df.time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time) 
df = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['time'].sum().sort_values('time', ascending=False)
print (df)
    name                   time
0    One 1 days 00:32:15.571836
1  Three 0 days 20:43:57.652740
2    Two 0 days 19:59:28.787253
```

---

```
df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['time'].sum().sort_values('time', ascending=False)
print (df)
   id                   time
0   1 1 days 00:32:15.571836
2   3 0 days 20:43:57.652740
1   2 0 days 19:59:28.787253
```

Last is possible convert timedeltas to `seconds` by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), another conversation are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion):

```
df.time = df.time.dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
   id          time
0   1  88335.571836
2   3  74637.652740
1   2  71968.787253
```

Comment: group by "id" is what I did, as names can be same for multiple persons, challenge was fetching the name at last while preparing response.. is there any way to read the name after groupby id and sort ? One way can be to create a clone data frame(of the initial data frame) and read from there. Any other efficient way

Comment: I am not sure if understand do you need `df.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=False)` ?